# Multiple vlookups in one cell

Tags: excel, vlookup

Ok I have two vlookups that both search from the same array but with different criterias.The first vlookup would search for the Price category. The second vlookup would seek the type of product.

This is an example array:

```
ID  Price   Type
1   Banana  Fruit
2   Apple   Fruit
3   Orange  Fruit
4   Corn Flakes Cereal
5   Monster Energy Drink
```

The syntax would be:

```
Search for the first vlookup, if there is no results, try to search for the second vlookup. 
If the first or second vlookup is true, then return value ID.
```

I have already made the vlookups but I have no idea how to combine both in one cell

Edit: Vlookups

```
=Vlookup(A2,E4:G8,2,0)
=Vlookup(B2,E4:G8,2,0)
```

And the lists:

```
A column    B column
List 1  List 2
Banana  Hardware
Carrot  Vegetable
Orange  Chocolate
Mango   Candy
Fruit
```

Comment: show your Vlookups please

Comment: Just added the vlookups

Comment: `A2` abd `B2` conatains `ID`'s?

Comment: I added also the lists to make it clearer.

Comment: Corresponding ID. I want to get the actual result.

Answer (score 0):

This formula returns corressponding ID if found value from `A2` or `B2` in ranges `F4:F8` or `G4:G8` respectively, or "not found in both columns" if both values not found:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(E4:E8,IFERROR(MATCH(A2,F4:F8,0),MATCH(B2,G4:G8,0))),"not found in both columns")
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be as simple as this:

```
=IFERROR(Vlookup(A2,E4:G8,2,0),Vlookup(B2,E4:G8,2,0))
```

Try to find one, if it fails try the other.

Comment: it doesn't work. `A2` contains `Banana`, cloumn `E` contains `Id`'s. And `Vlookup(A2,E4:G8,2,0)` tries to find `banana` in `Id`'s column.

Comment: @simoco Your response would imply that you assume that the given `vlookups` are not correct. I actually assume that the example array is not representative.